# How to create an element in XSLT with a dynamic attribute?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have some XML that looks something like this:

```
  <ExtensionObject>
    <Value xmlns="">
        <Key>key01</Key>
        <StringValue>somewords</StringValue>
    </Value>
    <Value xmlns="">
        <Key>key01</Key>
        <NumberValue>12345</NumberValue>
    </Value>

...........hundreds more Values..............
  </ExtensionObject>
```

I rather optimistically wrote XSLT like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/ExtensionObject">
    <VResult>
        <xsl:for-each select="Value">
            <xsl:variable name="fld">
                <Value><xsl:value-of select="Key"/></Value>
            </xsl:variable>
            <Result field="$fld">
                <Value>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="NumberValue">
                            <xsl:value-of select="NumberValue"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="StringValue"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </Value>
            </Result>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </VResult>
</xsl:template>
```

And expected to get this:

```
<VResult>
    <Result field="key01"><Value>somewords</Value></Result>
    <Result field="key02"><Value>12345</Value></Result>
    ...........hundreds more Values..............
</VResult>
```

Instead I got:

```
<VResult>
    <Result field="$fld"><Value>somewords</Value></Result>
    <Result field="$fld"><Value>12345</Value></Result>
    ...........hundreds more Values..............
</VResult>
```

Does anyone know how I can insert the field names with the key value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:attribute name="field"><xsl:value-of select="Key"/></xsl:attribute>
```

Comment: Yep. Or, `<Result field="{Key}">`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using for-each, it's always better to use the templates:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <VResults>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='*' />
        </VResults>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Value">
        <Result>
            <xsl:attribute name='field'><xsl:value-of select='Key' /></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </Result>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="NumberValue|StringValue">
        <Value><xsl:value-of select='.' /></Value>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Always? If that were the case, I don't think the language designers would have gone to the expense of including `for-each` in the definition. I write a lot of XSLT, and sometimes `for-each` makes a lot more sense. It's less powerful, which means it's more predictable, therefore easier to trace and debug.

Comment: Agreed. I should have made my comment less final. I should have said something like: it's preferrable when the template matching is obvious.