# xml create attribute with dynamic value using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the below XML. I need to add an attribute to the first 'Entity' node. This attribute should have the value from the attribute node 'A-AssetFileName'. There are multiple Entity nodes within Data/Entities.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Entity Id="347" ExternalId="SSI1006" LongName="School Smart Hand Held Rustproof Carbon Steel Pencil Sharpener, Assorted Color, Pack of 24" EntityTypeId="18" EntityTypeName="Parent SKU" ContainerId="2" ContainerName="Collaboration Master" OrganizationName="DL" CategoryId="360" CategoryName="Sharpners" CategoryLongName="Sharpners" CategoryPath="SchoolSupplies»School_Office_Supplies»Sharpners" CategoryLongNamePath="" ParentEntityId="360" ParentExternalId="Sharpners" ParentExtensionEntityId="0" ParentExtensionEntityExternalId="" ParentExtensionEntityContainerId="0" ParentExtensionEntityContainerName="" ParentExtensionEntityCategoryId="0" ParentExtensionEntityCategoryPath="" ParentExtensionEntityCategoryLongNamePath="" Locale="en_WW" Action="Add">
<Attributes>
    <Attribute Id="4039" Name="Parent SKU #" LongName="Product Number" InstanceRefId="-1" Sequence="-1" AttributeParentId="4000" AttributeParentName="Core Attribute Group" AttributeType="Simple" AttributeDataType="String" Locale="en_WW" Action="Add">
        <Values>
            <Value Id="0" Uom="" ValueRefId="-1" Sequence="-1" DisplayValue="" HasInvalidValue="False" Locale="en_WW" Action="Add">
                <![CDATA[9-07466-030]]>
            </Value>
        </Values>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute Id="4040" Name="Product Name" LongName="Product Name" InstanceRefId="-1" Sequence="-1" AttributeParentId="4000" AttributeParentName="Core Attribute Group" AttributeType="Simple" AttributeDataType="String" Locale="en_WW" Action="Add">
        <Values>
            <Value Id="0" Uom="" ValueRefId="-1" Sequence="-1" DisplayValue="" HasInvalidValue="False" Locale="en_WW" Action="Add">
                <![CDATA[School Smart Hand Held Rustproof Carbon Steel Pencil Sharpener]]>
            </Value>
        </Values>
    </Attribute>
   <Attribute Id="4122" Name="A-Assets" LongName="Assets" InstanceRefId="-1" Sequence="-1" AttributeParentId="4003" AttributeParentName="Media Attribute Group" AttributeType="ComplexCollection" AttributeDataType="String" Locale="en_WW" Action="Add">
        <Attributes>
            <Attribute Id="4122" Name="A-Assets Instance Record" LongName="Assets Instance Record" InstanceRefId="293" Sequence="0" AttributeParentId="4003" AttributeParentName="Media Attribute Group" AttributeType="Complex" AttributeDataType="String" Locale="en_WW" Action="Add">
                <Attributes>
                    <Attribute Id="4126" Name="A-AssetDescription" LongName="AssetDescription" InstanceRefId="-1" Sequence="-1" AttributeParentId="4122" AttributeParentName="A-Assets" AttributeType="Simple" AttributeDataType="String" Locale="en_WW" Action="Add">
                        <Values>
                            <Value Id="-1" Uom="" ValueRefId="0" Sequence="-1" DisplayValue="" HasInvalidValue="False" Locale="en_WW" Action="Add" />
                        </Values>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute Id="4127" Name="A-AssetDisplayName" LongName="AssetDisplayName" InstanceRefId="-1" Sequence="-1" AttributeParentId="4122" AttributeParentName="A-Assets" AttributeType="Simple" AttributeDataType="String" Locale="en_WW" Action="Add">
                        <Values>
                            <Value Id="-1" Uom="" ValueRefId="0" Sequence="-1" DisplayValue="" HasInvalidValue="False" Locale="en_WW" Action="Add" />
                        </Values>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute Id="4128" Name="A-AssetFileName" LongName="AssetFileName" InstanceRefId="-1" Sequence="-1" AttributeParentId="4122" AttributeParentName="A-Assets" AttributeType="Simple" AttributeDataType="String" Locale="en_WW" Action="Add">
                        <Values>
                            <Value Id="-1" Uom="" ValueRefId="0" Sequence="-1" DisplayValue="" HasInvalidValue="False" Locale="en_WW" Action="Add">
                                <![CDATA[SSI1006_SchoolSmart Sharpener_1.jpg]]>
                            </Value>
                        </Values>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute Id="4129" Name="A-AssetID" LongName="AssetID" InstanceRefId="-1" Sequence="-1" AttributeParentId="4122" AttributeParentName="A-Assets" AttributeType="Simple" AttributeDataType="String" Locale="en_WW" Action="Add">
                        <Values>
                            <Value Id="-1" Uom="" ValueRefId="0" Sequence="-1" DisplayValue="" HasInvalidValue="False" Locale="en_WW" Action="Add">
                                <![CDATA[991E8697FD394A17A70C0DA7A73ECE87]]>
                            </Value>
                        </Values>
                    </Attribute>
                </Attributes>
            </Attribute>
        </Attributes>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Relationships />
```

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092355/increment-attribute-value-dynamically-xslt **OR** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670712/how-to-create-an-element-in-xslt-with-a-dynamic-attribute

Comment: the below is the XSLT I used. It doesn't work.

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Entity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name='ProductImage'>
                <xsl:value-of select="//Attribute[@Name = A-AssetFileName]" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of changes that need to be done for the template matching `<Entity>`.

You have mentioned that the attribute needs to be included only for the first `<Entity>` node. In that case the matching template will look like

```
<xsl:template match="Entity[1]">
```

When selecting the value for attribute `@Name`, the value should be enclosed in single quotes `'` and additionally the XPath needs to be modified as below.

```
<xsl:value-of select="//Attribute[@Name = 'A-AssetFileName']/Values/Value" />
```

Lastly, when applying the other templates, you need to apply all nodes and attributes, else the attributes will not be applied.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
```

So the template will look like

```
<xsl:template match="Entity[1]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name='ProductImage'> 
            <xsl:value-of select="//Attribute[@Name = 'A-AssetFileName']/Values/Value" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```